# imap_search Unknown search criterion: SINCE

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to get all the emails sent from a specific email which are either sent this month or last month. I'm using the following code:

(note: the imap_open works, I put 3 dots since I can't show the connection details)

```
$imapStream = imap_open(...);

if (!$imapStream || !empty(imap_errors())) {
    return;
}

$emailIds = imap_search($imapStream, 'FROM ' . $email . ' SINCE ' .  date ( "d M Y", strToTime ( "-1 month" ) ));
```

Where `$email` is a `POST` parameter. However, when I run this, it doesn't give me all the emails. When looking into `imap_errors()`, it gives the following error:

```
Unknown search criterion: SINCE
```

Comment: Also make sure you're quoting the $email.  I don't know if that will solve your problem though.

Comment: I already found the error. Seems like imap doesn't give me the correct errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error. imap somehow doesn't give me the right errors.

I tried this line:

```
$emailIds = imap_search($imapStream, 'FROM "' . $email . '" SINCE 22-Jul-2012');
```

This worked. So the `SINCE` criterion wasn't unknown the date string wasn't right.